# How to edit specific line in a textfile?

Tags: c#, streamwriter, appendfile

I know, that i can use `ReadAllLines` method and edit line using it's index. But this way not good for huge files. For example, i have file with 800,000 lines, and i need to find a line, which contains "hello", and insert `"\tmy\tfriend"` string after this word. I can't read all file into RAM. Which way is the best for HUGE files?
I tried to use StreamWriter, but it's append the end of the file.

```
var writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(...));
```

Comment: It's good to avoid very large text files in the first place, but if you cannot avoid it, you would probably want to stream. Think "sed". That also means that you will probably need to stream the altered output to a different file and do some renaming and clean up when done.

Comment: What mode did you open the StreamWriter in? Showing the code you have tried so far would let us help you. Please edit the question rather than put the code in a comment.

Comment: Why "can't read all file into RAM"? Maybe there are files with 300MB or more.

Comment: With the usual 'flat' storage model of a regular text file in a traditional file system, you are condemned to overwrite most of the file, starting from the point of insertion. Basically, every character needs to move away to another place in the file to make room for the preceding characters. If you frequently make these changes, then you may be better off using a database-like model as a working copy, i.e. a table where each line has its own record. At regular intervals, apply all changes together and rewrite/replace the original file in one go.

Comment: @i486 This is some requirements :(

Comment: @RuudHelderman I can use only .txt files. And it's potentially huge.

Comment: Read the first line from file. Insert text where applicable. Write the line to a temporary file. Repeat these steps for each line in the file, until you reach end of file. Finally, move the temporary file to the original file. Memory footprint is roughly the size of a single line. Expected duration is proportional to the size of the file, so it may take a while on huge files, but that's the price you pay for using text files only. Earlier, Dmitry Bychenko posted this approach as an answer, but it was downvoted (without explanation) and then deleted.

Comment: @RuudHelderman probably because he was reading all the lines in memory.

Comment: @Murrchalkina: your code still does not show which mode the file was opened in.

Comment: @Alberto That answer was using [LINQ to Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects) from end to end. Each line is read 'on demand', right before it will be written, and released immediately after. Released objects may or may not be reclaimed by the GC; that's up to the .NET runtime to decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to rewrite the entire file every time.

Read the first file and write back to a second temporary file. When you encounter the line that matches your search append the the additional string and continue write the rest of the file.
At the end replace the original file and delete the temporary one.

```
using (var fs1 = new FileStream("original.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (var fs2 = new FileStream("temp.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using var sr = new StreamReader(fs1);
    using var sw = new StreamWriter(fs2);

    string? line = null;
    do
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        if(line != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("hello") == true)
            {
                line = $"{line}\tmy\tfriend";
            }

            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    while (line != null);
}

File.Copy("temp.txt", "original.txt", true);
File.Delete("temp.txt");
```

Instead of `File.Copy`+`File.Delete` you could also use `File.Move`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the best and clear answer.